# What happens if I edit a constant value in PL SQL?

Tags: plsql

Here is my PL SQL code

I am intentionally trying to change the value of  notice_period_in_days to see what error I am going to get.

It throws the error "PLS-00363: expression 'NOTICE_PERIOD_IN_DAYS' cannot be used as an assignment target"

but why the  immediate first line after the declare keyword is not executed, I am expecting the error only on  the line where I assign a new value for notice_period_in_days (i.e) 50 .

when i compile and run  this the complete block is failing , Can you someone explain me the reason for this

```
set serveroutput on;

declare 
notice_period_in_days CONSTANT NUMBER := 60;

begin 
dbms_output.put_line (notice_period_in_days);
notice_period_in_days := 50;
dbms_output.put_line (notice_period_in_days);
end ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dbms_output.put_line` doesn't output anything until the entire PL/SQL block is complete. Since it's erroring out before completion, nothing is printed to the screen.

Comment: is mostly correct. But it actually goes a bit further. Dbms_Output does not output anything, ever. It creates an internal buffer. This buffer is then processed or not processed by the client. It is the client that is bypassing the message output. Yea, most likely due to the exception.